# elements is undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I am getting error "elements is undefined" in Javascript

```
function ImportExcelMapping() 
{
    debugger;

    var str = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++ ) {
      if (document.forms[0].elements[i].type == "hidden") {
        str += '<input type=\"hidden\" name="' + elements[i].name + '" value=\"' + elements[i].value + '">';
     }
   }
    // rest of function
}
```

please help

Answer (score 7):

```
elements[i].name
```

Where is elements defined? Is that supposed to be `document.forms[0].elements[i]`?

### EDIT:

Since you seem to be confused still, I'll add a bit more detail. Hopefully this clears it up.

You either need to declare `elements` at the top of your function, like so:

```
function ImportExcelMapping() {
    debugger;

    var str = "";
    var elements = document.forms[0].elements;
    // rest of function
}
```

**Or**

You need to change the line that's breaking to this:

```
str += '<input type=\"hidden\" name="' + document.forms[0].element[i].name + '" value=\"' + document.forms[0].element[i].value + '">';
```

Comment: str += '<input type=\"hidden\" name="' + elements[i].name + '" value=\"' + elements[i].value + '">';

Comment: @DineshChauhan: Yes, because obviously `elements` is not defined. You have to define it.

Comment: @DineshChauhan I added a little more detail. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: @Yatrix : It is working know but i have one more issue when i am catching ID from hidden field it returns me 0

Comment: @DineshChauhan You're welcome. If this answered your question, please upvote the answer and accept it. That second issue should be a separate question which I or someone else would be happy to help you with. =)

Answer (score 2):

Well you never defined `elements`.  You probably just need to declare it:

`var elements = document.forms[0].elements[i];`